# matching comma separated string to a database field and sort the result to be in the same order as the comma separated string

Tags: php, mysql

I have a variable with comma separated string, so I'm matching them with the values of another table field, how do I sort the result by the order in which the comma separated strings are structured. thank you currently I'm doing this.

```
$email_address = test@test.com,test@test2.com,test@test3.com,; 
 
$sql ="SELECT id,company_ref,name FROM  employee WHERE email_address IN ('".str_replace(",", "','",    $email_address)."')";
 
$result = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
$total = mysqli_num_rows($result);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ORDER BY FIELD

```
ORDER BY field(email_address, 'test@test.com','test@test2.com','test@test3.com');
```

Reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field